# Can Hyper-v 2012 Server Bare Metal (the free version) boot into a VM automatically?

Tags: hyper-v-server-2012

If I have two guests installed using Hyper-v 2012 "evaluation" (unlimited) *free version*, can I make it so a guest OS boots automatically and the user never sees the Hyper-v login?

I have a laptop, and I want to put two OSes on it with Hyper-v as the hypervisor at the bare metal level.  But, I want to be able to make the machine bypass the standard Hyper-v control-alt-delete and go straight to my Windows 7 VM without user intervention.

Answer (score 1):

Hyper-V Server has no means locally to display a virtual console session. You would have to access the VMs through Hyper-V manager, MMC, WinRM, or some other remote management tool. Are you sure you're not looking for simple dual boot?

Comment: No.  But I started thinking that after I asked.  I'm trying it.  Thanks.